# Facebook graph api for getting user facebook fan page list

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a problem while getting the list of facebook fan pages using the graph api.

I am using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{userfacebookid}/accounts?access_token={access_token}&scope=manage_pages
```

But I am getting empty result like this:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Comment: You've added the scope on the end of your api request, but the scope should be on your login url to ask for the appropriate permission when a user authorizes your app I believe. e.g in the php-sdk $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope"=>"manage_pages"));  That way your access_token should give you the correct permissions to access the account connection.

Answer (score 4):

**ONE:** You should start by reading the authentication flow. Here's the [Server-Side Authentication document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/)

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &redirect_url=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
   &state=SOME_ARBITRARY_BUT_UNIQUE_STRING
```

Here you should ask for the `manage_pages` permission

**TWO:** Once you have the user access token with this permission you can retrieve the pages the user administer:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{userfacebookid}/accounts?access_token={access_token}
```

**THREE:** This won't retrieve the pages the user is fan of!

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced same problem while getting our pages(i.e., created by us) and i tried but at last i got the solution

**While authentication time u have to pass permissions like below**

**https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_url=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&scope=manage_pages,user_subscriptions**